# event handler on a collection of polygons in Bing Maps AJAX not triggering

Tags: ajax, bing-maps

I have created a concentric ring object/collection using the following code. I would like to then move/drag the collection around the map,highlighting locations of interest within those rings. As you can see I have added an event handler to the collection but when I try to drag the collection on my map it never triggers the event handler. Any ideas why not?   I have confirmed that the event handler is in place.

Using v7 of the Bing API.
I have left out the handlers in the code example below, they just do simple alerts("got here");

```
function GetMap(){

       map.entities.push(AddRings(center));
}




 function AddRings(center) {
        var circleCollection = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
        circleCollection.push(AddCircle(center.latitude, center.longitude, .05, new MM.Color(155, 2, 2, 2)));
        circleCollection.push(AddCircle(center.latitude, center.longitude, 5, new MM.Color(255, 0, 255, 0)));
        circleCollection.push(AddCircle(center.latitude, center.longitude, 20, new MM.Color(255, 255, 0, 0)));
        circleCollection.push(AddCircle(center.latitude, center.longitude, 10, new MM.Color(255, 0, 0, 255)));
        MM.Events.addHandler(circleCollection, 'mousedown', StartDragHandler);
        MM.Events.addHandler(circleCollection, 'mouseup', EndDragHandler);
        MM.Events.addHandler(circleCollection, 'mouseout', EndDragHandler);

        return circleCollection;
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen in every browser? I've had a similar problem on IE when using jQuery on the same page.

Comment: Well, now that I've actually read the code I'm not sure that you can add the events to the collection itself. Have you tried adding the event handler to each circle?

Comment: To your first comment. I am currently only testing in IE and I do have jQuery on the page so I am going to do some testing without it.

Comment: To your second comment. No I haven't tried adding to each circle but I will give it a shot.

Comment: I tried adding it to each polygon/circle but then the each circle moves independently from the "bullseye" that I want to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EntityCollection class does not have mouse events. You can see which events this collection has here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx

You have to add the events to each shape in the collection.

Also, it looks like you are trying to draw a complex polygon. Have you considered using the AdvanceShapes module: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh921952.aspx